# Java gets me strange output matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, vector

I've programmed a function to reorder rows and columns of a matrix and found out a strange output and I can't figure out whats wrong.
I've made a function just to simple specify what's going on (this is not the original function but is just to understand what's the problem).

```
public static int[][] hey(){
        int[][] res = new int[10][];
        int[] v = new int[3];
        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                v[i]=i+j;
            }
            res[j]=v;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

and the output is a matrix where every vector is the last row of what it should return [[9,10,11],[9,10,11],...,[9,10,11]] and it should return [[0,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],...,[9,10,11]]

What's wrong??

Comment: What is a sample input and the expected/actual output? I don't understand your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move creation of v vector inside the first for loop. Otherwise each line of res array/matrix will reference to the same v vector which will contain the last 3 values.

```
public static int[][] hey(){
        int[][] res = new int[10][];

        for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
            int[] v = new int[3];
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
                v[i]=i+j;
            }
            res[j]=v;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `res[j]=v;`. Here you're setting the dimension 1 array to the *same* instance, i.e. all elements in `res` refer to `v` and thus have the same contents.

Instead you might just do `int[][] res = new int[10][3];` and `res[j][i]=i+j;`.

Note that `int[][] res` actually means that `res` is an array of `int[]` arrays, i.e. `res[x]` refers to an `Object` (all arrays are objects). That means that `res[x]` actually contains a *reference* and not a value and hence `res[j] = v` updates that reference to point to `v` (which you never change).

**Update:**

As per your comment the length of dimension 2 is varying. In that case you need to initialize the elements inside your outer loop:

```
for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
  res[j] = new int[variable_length];
}
```

Then you can still do `res[j][i]` (of course you'd iterate over `i = 0` to `i < res[j].length`).

Comment: i know that if i do that it gives me what it should, but in my case i'll have vectors with different lengths and I want to "insert" them like this.

Comment: @BernardoBraga in that case you need to dynamically initialize `res[j]` , I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: that will work, but why can't I do res[j]=v? i've made prints inside the fors and is everything ok, i'm just curious about this non-sense output

Comment: @BernardoBraga you _can_ do `res[j]=v` as long as you reassign/recreate `v` in every iteration. Doing so would just be superfluous in the code you posted, your actual code might be a different matter.